# How do I center a rectangular div inside another rectangular div

Tags: css, viewport

I'm trying to make a rectangular div that's 95% the width of the viewport and 20% high. But I want another rectangular div inside of that, that is vertically and horizontally centered with a slight2px margin.

```
.Outer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 95vw;
    max-height: 20vh;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    }
.Inner {
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: See all those **Related** items over on the right. Try checking those out.

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon requirements. But according to question, here is the answer. Please take a look and let me know in case of any issue

```css
.Outer {
  width: 95vw;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Inner {
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Outer">
  <div class="Inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use relative measuring units just in case you are dealing with a responsive design. The `.outer` box is `display: table` and the `Inner` is `display: table-cell`. They sit perfectly together and the 2px margin your requested is provided by a 2px padding from `.Outer`

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 16px/1.428'Consolas';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.Outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 3%;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 95vw;
  max-height: 20vh;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 2px;
}
.Inner {
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section class="Outer">
  <section class="Inner"></section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% this is what your looking for because this has *Magic Numbers*, but here is a JSFiddle of what I came up with using your provided code.

```css
#Outer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 95vw;
    max-height: 20vh;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }
#Inner {
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    width: 95%;
    height: 50%;
    position: aboslute;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-left: 2.5vw;
    }
```

```html
<div id=Outer>
  <div id=Inner>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/089ne8e9/5/)

Hopefully this helps and you could mess around with it to use percentages on the viewpoints instead of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to center a div vertically, I have a couple classes that help me to do it.

```css
    .outer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 95vw;
    max-height: 20vh;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    }

    .inner {
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    width: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .valign-wrap {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    }

    .valign-wrap .valign {
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer valign-wrap">

    <div class="inner valign center"></div>
  
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jujogi/pphupuus/)

I always recommend **add these classes to your projects**, they are very useful. Good luck!